# Android.Filtering using if statement getting data from JSON

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I am reading all data from a `json` file but I want to filter out all "Delivered" delivery_status. So I use `if(status == jobj.getString(DELIVERY_STATUS))`. BUT NOTHING WORKS. please help me

The output MUST BE only:

```
{"delivery_id":"1","client_firstname":"Jhonny",delivery_status":"Pending"}
{"delivery_id":"4","client_firstname":"Marie",delivery_status":"On the Road"}
```

**AndroidActivity.java (Code Snippet)**

```
public static final String DELIVERY_ID = "delivery_id";
public static final String CLIENT_FIRSTNAME = "client_firstname";
public static final String DELIVERY_STATUS = "delivery_status";

JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("delivery");

                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                String status = "Delivered";

                                if(status == jobj.getString(DELIVERY_STATUS)) {
                                    item.put(DELIVERY_ID, jobj.getString(DELIVERY_ID));
                                    item.put(CLIENT_FIRSTNAME, jobj.getString(CLIENT_FIRSTNAME));
                                    item.put(DELIVERY_STATUS, jobj.getString(DELIVERY_STATUS));
                                }

                                Item_List.add(item);
                            } // for loop e
```

**.json file**

```
"delivery":[{"delivery_id":"1","client_firstname":"Jhonny",delivery_status":"Pending"}
    {"delivery_id":"2","client_firstname":"Mario",delivery_status":"Delivered"}  
    {"delivery_id":"3","client_firstname":"Jason",delivery_status":"Delivered"}
    {"delivery_id":"4","client_firstname":"Marie",delivery_status":"On the Road"}]
```

Comment: `if(status == jobj.getString(DELIVERY_STATUS))` this is not the way of comparing two `Strings` in java

Comment: how? can you help me? just a code snippet.  i am comparing a list of array

Comment: google, google is your friend, ask google for `compare string in java`

Comment: i tried it..and also i think my problem here is not just comparing the string.. anyone can help me?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @Doraemon Can you use `Log` to see whats happening in your code? And do string comparison with `equals()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to do like this,

```
     if(jobj.getString("delivery_status").equals("Delivered")){

      //your code
     }
```